Optimizing CustomReactiveOidcSessionRegistry for Redis in Spring Security OIDC
I'm seeking guidance on how to properly implement the OidcProviderSessionRepository. I have several questions:

What is the correct way to implement OidcProviderSessionRepository?
Are there any built-in implementations provided by Spring Security?
If I need to create a custom implementation, which key methods should I implement?
How would this implementation differ if I were using Redis for session storage?

Here’s a snippet of my current class structure:
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public final class CustomReactiveOidcSessionRegistry implements ReactiveOidcSessionRegistry {
  private final OidcProviderSessionRepository sessions;
  
  @Override
  public Mono<void> saveSessionInformation(OidcSessionInformation info) {
    return this.sessions.save(info);
  }

  @Override
  public Mono<OidcSessionInformation> removeSessionInformation(String clientSessionId) {
    return this.sessions.removeByClientSessionId(clientSessionId);
  }

  @Override
  public Flux<OidcSessionInformation> removeSessionInformation(OidcLogoutToken token) {
    return token.getSessionId() != null ?
        this.sessions.removeBySessionIdAndIssuerAndAudience(...) :
        this.sessions.removeBySubjectAndIssuerAndAudience(...);
  }
}

I am unable to find an interface to implement the OidcProviderSessionRepository.
